# Question about implicit method in Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in 2D and trying to solve these equations by using **implicit** method in time.

My question is: do we need to derive pressure Poisson equation to solve it? If not, how can I ensure that the continuity equation is satisfied?

Thank you in advance.

Best.

Comment: As far as I remember, you should be able to find this in the book "Navier-Stokes Equations: Theory and Numerical Analysis" from Roger Temam, especially in the later chapters.

Comment: Thank you, Fritz. I will look for some things in that book. Best, Ann.